# Get string between two regex

Tags: linux, bash

I have a string that is like that(comes from a curl command's body):
The server returns an xml

```
Package installed in 116ms.
  </log>
</data>
<status code="200">ok</status>
```

Sometimes this strong can become or some other error:

```
<status code="500">java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid.</status>
```

I'm wonder what would be the best way to grep the status code 200 and if it is not 200. Give an error like "Status code is 500 with error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid

So far I have some improvement:

> sed -n "s|<status code="200">(.*)|\1|p" test.log

But how do I get the status code too with sed

Comment: `the best way` the best way is to XML parser to parse XML files. So grep is not the best way. You can't parse XML with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get attribute `code` of node `status`, just:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//status/@code)' -
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking. One question. How to get the message too?

Comment: `string(//status)`. I am very bad at xpath https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths , you could do like `'concat(string(//status/@code), "|", string(//status))'`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- (by whatever means) the `<status>...</status>` string has been extracted from the `curl` output
- the string is formatted as in OP's examples (eg, no embedded line breaks between the `<string>` and `</string>` strings; no double quotes, left/right carrots in the data; nothing that would require a more complex regex pattern than used below)

One idea would be to compare the string against a regex and if there's a match then obtain the desired info from the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array, eg:

```
regex='<status code="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<'

for string in '<status code="200">ok</status>' '<status code="500">java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid.</status>' 'ignore this string'
do
    unset error_no error_msg

    printf "\n######## %s\n\n" "${string}"

    if [[ "${string}" =~ $regex ]]
    then
        error_no="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        error_msg="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi

    typeset -p BASH_REMATCH

    printf "\nerror_no  : ${error_no}\n"
    printf "error_msg : ${error_msg}\n"
done
```

This generates:

```
######## <status code="200">ok</status>

declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="<status code=\"200\">ok<" [1]="200" [2]="ok")

error_no  : 200
error_msg : ok

######## <status code="500">java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid.</status>

declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="<status code=\"500\">java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid.<" [1]="500" [2]="java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid.")

error_no  : 500
error_msg : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Archive not valid.

######## ignore this string

declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=()

error_no  :
error_msg :
```

**NOTES:**

- the `regex` variable could likely be expanded to address additional formats but at some point you start re-inventing an XML parser

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I edited my comment. The error message can be anything

Comment: with your latest update (a 4-line string) this answer still works and generates output of `200` and `ok`; at this point this answer/code (still) does what you want; if you have additional examples that do not work I'd suggest working on the `regex` definition and if you're unable to get it to work then ask a new question, making sure to provide your (modified) code